# How do I use Chinese characters in Java?

Tags: java, character, cjk

I'm trying to use Chinese characters in Java GUI components. I have changed my keyboard output to Chinese and can type in Netbeans in Chinese. Further, I can compile these Java files. However, when I run these programs, the characters are displayed as English question marks. What can I do to change this?

Comment: Does the font support unicode values?

Comment: Where are you displaying the output? In a console window on Windows? If you're using a non-Chinese version of Windows, then the console window most likely can't display Chinese characters.

Comment: The output is displayed on GUI components e.g. JButtons, JLabels, etc. displayed on the monitor, not the command line. I do not have a Chinese version of windows. Can anything be done?

Comment: Do other countries have to learn english to write code in our languages?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to make sure that you are compiling with a suitable setting for the encoding option to javac.

Second, you have to be running with a suitable character encoding. In most cases, setting  -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 will do it, but it also depends on what sort of program (command line? GUI?) and what environment you're running it in.

Comment: Gosh, this is all new to me. Up until 10 days ago, the computer was just a utility to get me online. I decided to start programming after reading an into to programming with Java book. It all made sense to me, and I started writing my first program. I'm almost done, but I need to resolve this Chinese character situation. I guess what I'm saying is that I'm brand new to computers, and I don't understand many of the terms being bandied about. Could you explain further, please? By the way, my program is all GUI. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the shortest answer is best here so I recommend you read [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) excellent blog post on "The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)" by Joel Spolsky.

I think the couple minutes spent reading this will be more than worth it.